# How to pass a parameter from a php file to AJAX js file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, parameters

I'm new to AJAX. Here's my problem:

1. I am calling my `index.php` file with this code:

   ```
    http://www.moodurian.com/wall/index.php?CourseId=36
   ```
2. My `index.php` file has this code:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wall.js">
   ```
3. I have a file `wall.js` that contains this code portion:

   ```
   $.ajax({type: "POST",
           url: "message_ajax.php?CID=36",
           data: dataString,
           ...
   ```

It calls the file `message_ajax.php` and passes to `message_ajax.php` the parameter named CID that has the value of 36.

Now what I really want to do is **not** hard code the value `36` in the `wall.js` line that says:

```
url: "message_ajax.php?CID=36",
```

**Instead**, I want the line to say this:

```
url: "message_ajax.php?CID=CourseId",
   ...
```

I tried it, but somehow my `message_ajax.php` doesn't receive the value `36` through that CID parameter.

So what I want to do actually, is to have my `index.php` file pass the a value (in this example, `36`) to `wall.js`, and then have `wall.js` pass that same value (in my example, value `36`) to `message_ajax.php`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that your course ID (in this example, `36`) is stored in a variable called `CourseId`. If that's the case, instead of this:

```
url: "message_ajax.php?CID=CourseId",
```

you want to use this:

```
url: "message_ajax.php?CID=" + CourseId,
```

That way it forms the URL string by concatenating the static part (`"message_ajax.php?CID="`) with the dynamic part (the `CourseId` variable's value).

Comment: Gosh, Anthony, you answered within 1 minute!? That's super fast. Thank you! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the CID in your url string send it as a `data` parameter

```
var CourseId = '36' ; // In this case

var dataString = { 'CID' : CourseId}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "message_ajax.php",
    data: dataString , 
    dataType : 'json',

    success : function(result){
  }
});
```

Or you can do this

```
url: "message_ajax.php?CID=" + CourseId
```

By doing so you won't be seeing the parameters in the Query sting of the current Window...

Comment: Super, Sushanth. I mean I took 30 minutes to craft my question, and I get 2 answers in 2 minutes. Fantastic...!!!